# Angular firebase why same function only works once?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got upload.service and 2 different modules with some components.

> upload.service , upload.ts  is imported to components->
>
> Upload.module (
>
> upload.component (everything works fine (i can upload and get photo
>   url data from database)
>
> )
>
> Ui.module )
>
> upload.component (same function but I can't see photo , no url)
>
> )

**Working component (upload.component) :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { UploadService } from '../shared/upload.service';
import { Upload } from '../shared/upload';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'uploads-list',
  templateUrl: './uploads-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploads-list.component.scss'],
})
export class UploadsListComponent implements OnInit {

  uploads: Observable<Upload[]>;
  showSpinner = true;

  constructor(private upSvc: UploadService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploads = this.upSvc.getUploads();
    this.uploads.subscribe(() => this.showSpinner = false);
  }
}
```

**Not working component ( ui.component 0 errors) :**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { UploadService } from "../../uploads/shared/upload.service";
import { Upload } from "../../uploads/shared/upload";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
  selector: 'top-nav',
  templateUrl: './top-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-nav.component.scss'],
})
export class TopNavComponent implements OnInit {
  uploads: Observable<Upload[]>;
  show = false;
  showSpinner = true;
  toggleCollapse() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  constructor(private upSvc: UploadService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploads = this.upSvc.getUploads();
    console.log("paimama upload :", this.uploads)
    this.uploads.subscribe(() => this.showSpinner = false);
  }

}
```

I think the main problem is that I am trying to use these functions and variables from one service in two different modules - components. How to retrieve it so it would work ?

Edit (the function I am calling) :

```
 getUploads() {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(`${this.auth.userId}`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        return { $key, ...data };
      });

    });
    return this.uploads;
  }
```

Html (working one in upload.component) :

```
<h3>File Uploads</h3>

<div *ngFor="let upload of uploads | async">
  <upload-detail [upload]='upload'></upload-detail>
  <img src="{{upload.url}}" alt="">
</div>

<loading-spinner *ngIf="showSpinner"></loading-spinner>

<hr>

<upload-form></upload-form>
```

HTML (not working ui.component)

```
<div *ngFor="let upload of uploads | async">
      <img src="{{upload.url}}" alt="">
    </div>
```

or

Comment: What type of observable is your `UploadService`? Can it have values emitted more than once?

Comment: Edited: function that I call from uploadservices.

Comment: You are creating a new observable on each call. Create a property in your service and set the observable to that, then you can use that observable in your components so they share the same stream. The scope of `this.uploads` is only in the content of each `getUploads` call.

Comment: Could you please try to explain with my code example? Sorry but still didn't get it.

Comment: I will show example in an answer.

Comment: If you are talking about that :   uploads: Observable<Upload[]>; , then I use it in my uploadservice.

Comment: How you showing it in html?

Comment: I made an edit with html

Comment: Try removing `this.uploads.subscribe(() => this.showSpinner = false);` and check. may be multiple subscription causing the problem.

Comment: Didn't worked ;(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are re-initializing your service observable each time the `getUploads()` method is called. This causes each component to be subscribing to a different observable, so they will not be in sync.

Don't do this if you want all components to subscribe to the same stream.

**Change this:**

```
getUploads() {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(`${this.auth.userId}`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
        return actions.map((a) => {
            const data = a.payload.val();
            const $key = a.payload.key;
            return { $key, ...data };
        });

    });

    return this.uploads;
}
```

**To this:**

```
getUploads() {
    if (!this.uploads) {
        this.uploads = this.db.list(`${this.auth.userId}`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
            return actions.map((a) => {
                const data = a.payload.val();
                const $key = a.payload.key;
                return { $key, ...data };
            });
        });
    }

    return this.uploads;
}
```

Now each component should get the same exact observable stream.

Let me know if that doesn't help.

---

**Update:**

Another approach you can take is to create a custom subject and use that as an observable. Subscribe to that observable in both components, and when you get uploads from the db you can add the upload to the stream. Each component will get the upload you add to that stream.

```
@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
    uploadSubject: ReplaySubject<Upload> = new ReplaySubject();
    upload$: Observable<Upload> = this.uploadSubject.asObservable();

    getUploads() {
        this.http.get(url).subscribe((upload: Upload) => {
            this.uploadSubject.next(upload);
        });
    }
}
```

Now in **any** component, you can just subscribe to `upload$` and any time the `getUploads()` is called, every single component subscribing to `upload$` will get the value.

```
export class Component1 {
    upload: Upload;

    constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) {
        uploadService.upload$.subscribe((upload: Upload) => this.upload = upload);
    }
}

export class Component2 {
    upload: Upload;

    constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) {
        uploadService.upload$.subscribe((upload: Upload) => this.upload = upload);
    }
}
```

With this approach, just make sure to call `getUploads` somewhere, because the components are not calling it; they are just listening for the value it will broadcast.

---

**Update 2:**

Now I am modifying your code to work with my example above. Since this is using your code, it may not work because I may be missing certain things you have in your environment. But the original "Update" above works 100%, so use that as a guideline to get your code working. Just read the code and make sure you understand what it does and you will see that it will work for what you're doing.

**UploadService:**

```
@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
    uploadStream: ReplaySubject<Upload[]> = new ReplaySubject();
    uploads$: Observable<Upload[]> = this.uploadStream.asObservable();

    constructor() {
        this.getUploads();
    }

    getUploads() {
        this.db.list(`${this.auth.userId}`)
            .map((actions: Action[]) => {
                return actions.map((action: Action) => {
                    const data = action.payload.val();
                    const $key = action.payload.key;

                    return new Upload({ $key, ...data });
                });
            })
            .subscribe((uploads: Upload[]) => {
                this.uploadStream.next(uploads);
            });
    }
}
```

**UploadsListComponent:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { UploadService } from '../shared/upload.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'uploads-list',
  templateUrl: './uploads-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploads-list.component.scss'],
})
export class UploadsListComponent {
  constructor(public uploadService: UploadService) {}
}
```

**UploadListComponent template:**

```
<h3>File Uploads</h3>

<div *ngFor="let upload of uploadService.uploads$ | async">
  <upload-detail [upload]='upload'></upload-detail>
  <img src="{{upload.url}}" alt="">
</div>

<loading-spinner *ngIf="showSpinner"></loading-spinner>

<hr>

<upload-form></upload-form>
```

Now you can take the same component approach as above on your second component.

Comment: Nop, that didnt worked. Now tried only includint another component in a component I want to use that file. <uploads-list></uploads-list> . Shows almost everything in another component, except data from database.

Comment: Okay can you explain step by step what is supposed to happen? Maybe I misunderstood your question. For example: 1. Load photo from database, 2. Do this, 3. This should happen as a result. Please try to make it very clear and simple.

Comment: I made a service which lets upload files, upload their name, url to database and then show files url.  so my function is : Getting data from database(url, name and etc.).

Comment: @Andrius La. Then you create a object for itm right? export class UploadFiles {

    url: string;
    name: string;
    ...
}

Comment: Upload.service : 1.Uploads photo to storage 2. Saves data to an Object 3. Get's data from an Object . Upload.service uses upload.ts for an interface where I wrote (key,name,url and etc.)

Comment: Don't know what You've done there, but that won't help me with mine function, because it's way too different.

Comment: It will help you. It solves your problem exactly as you specified. Just because it looks different doesn't mean it won't work :P save your current code on the branch you are working on, create a new branch and try out my example and you will see. Try to make sure you understand the code... once you read it fully and understand it, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Okey, but could you help me to understand that code you wrote with my code ? It would be really way more better than this.

Comment: Okay I will update again using your code as an example. Keep in mind, your code is based on your environment, and I don't have your environment, so can't assure it will work using your code. But my example works 100%.

Comment: Added second example. If that doesn't work for you, you need to be more specific because that solves the problem you said, so maybe you just aren't being clear enough. I've had these use cases before and this sort of code works well for me.

Comment: Generic type 'Action<T>' r
equires 1 type argument(s).

Comment: The `Action` is just an example type, because your response has an `actions` variable. You can remove that or use `any`.

Comment: did everything as you said, now I am not getting photo url in any of the components (I am only getting [object object] .

 getUploads() {
    this.db.list(`${this.auth.userId}`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
        return actions.map((a) => {
          const data = a.payload.val();
          const $key = a.payload.key;

          return new Upload({ $key, ...data });
        });
      })
      .subscribe((uploads: Upload[]) => {
        this.uploadStream.next(uploads);
      });
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167660/discussion-between-lansana-and-andrius-la).